# Yii List view sorting for relation values

Tags: yii

In yii project i am using listview to display data in table view.

Sorting option working for existed database colums.

Now i want to display relation values in list view.
Those values i am getting from relations. 
Like:

```
 'noOfImages'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Images','user_id')
```

Now how to add sorting for 'noOfImages' column.

```
 <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->noOfImages); ?></td>
```

In the above code `'noOfImages'` is not a db column . it's an calculated value through relations of that model.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To access the property add `public $noOfImages` to your model. Sure you can do calculations you need(for example in `afterFind` method)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. once i place the property public $pages_viewed in model , i did not get any result